# how to find the angle of reflection of the beam from the line

Tags: java, math, geometry, linear-algebra, algebra

I have a line (**x1**, **y1**) (**x2**, **y2**) and a ray at an angle “**a**”, I need to find the angle of reflection of the ray from this line, as in the picture below. Thanks [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beam starting direction is vector **Dir** `(dir.x, dir.y)`
Unit normal **N** `(n.x, n.y)` for given line is

```
l = sqrt((y1 - y2)^2 + (x2 - x1)^2)
n.x = (y1 - y2) / l
n.y = (x2 - x1) / l
```

After reflection tangential component of **Dir** is inverted and normal component remains the same, so we can write equations for new direction using dot product:

```
 dot = dir.x * n.x + dir.y * n.y

 //after reflection
 newdir.x = dir.x - 2 * dot * n.x
 newdir.y = dir.y - 2 * dot * n.y
```

If you really need angle, use `atan2` function

```
angle = atan2(newdir.y, newdir.x)
```

but in the most of cases reflection/hitting stuff might be solved with vector components without direct using of angles